# native функции

Tags: java

Если мы используем нативные функции, то программа на Java теряет свойство кроссплатформености? **Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В широком смысле, да, теряет. Но практически может и не терять, например, в тех случаях, когда вместе с кодом на Java поставляются разнообразные версии нативных библиотек, и каждая покрывает ту конкретную платформу, на которой Java-приложение планируется запускать.